# Why can't I navigate to my Screen using onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SaveProfileImage, { profileImage })}?

Tags: react-native, navigation, save, screen

I'm developing an app where I have a screen called Add, other called Save, that I navigate between them using `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Save', { image })}` inside a button, so I tried to do the same on another screen called profile that should navigate to the screen SaveProfileImage, but when I try this, I get the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params') and I can't understand what can be so wrong in my codes:

Here is the Profile codes:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/firestore');
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Profile({ navigation }, props) {
    const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [hasGalleryPermission, setHasGalleryPermission] = useState(null);
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const { currentUser, posts } = props;

        if (props.route.params.uid === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
            setUser(currentUser)
            setUserPosts(posts)
        }
        else {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .doc(props.route.params.uid)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.exists) {
                        setUser(snapshot.data());
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('does not exist')
                    }
                })
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('posts')
                .doc(props.route.params.uid)
                .collection('userPosts')
                .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        const id = doc.id;
                        return { id, ...data }
                    })
                    setUserPosts(posts)
                });
        };

        (async () => {
            const galleryStatus = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
            setHasGalleryPermission(galleryStatus.status === 'granted');
        })();
    }, [props.route.params.uid, props.following]);
    
    const pickImage = async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [1, 1],
        quality: 1,
      });
  
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
      };
    };
  
  
    if (hasGalleryPermission === false) {
      return <View />;
    };
    if (hasGalleryPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to gallery</Text>;
    };

    const onLogout = () => {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    };

    if (user === null) {
        return <View />
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }}
            style={{ flex: 1 }} />}
            <Image source={{ uri: props.route.params.profileImage }} />
            <View style={styles.containerInfo}>
                <Text>{user.name}</Text>
                <Text>{user.state}</Text>
                <Text>{user.city}</Text>
                <Text>{user.email}</Text>

                {props.route.params.uid !== firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}
                <Button title='Pick Image From Gallery' onPress={() => pickImage()} />
                <Button title='Save'
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SaveProfileImage',
                    { profileImage })} />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    numColumns={3}
                    horizontal={false}
                    data={userPosts}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View
                            style={styles.containerImage}>

                            <Image
                                style={styles.image}
                                source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }}
                            />
                        </View>

                    )}

                />
            </View>
            <Button
                title='Logout'
                onPress={() => onLogout()}
            />
        </View>

    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    containerInfo: {
        margin: 20
    },
    containerImage: {
        flex: 1 / 3
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1 / 1
    }
})
const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    posts: store.userState.posts,
    following: store.userState.following
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

The app.js has a navigation container to control these screens:

```
<NavigationContainer >
 <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Main'>
  <Stack.Screen name='Main' component={MainScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name='Add' component={AddScreen}
   navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  <Stack.Screen name='Save' component={SaveScreen}
   navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  <Stack.Screen name='SaveProfileImage' component={SaveProfileImageScreen}
   navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  <Stack.Screen name='Comment' component={CommentScreen}
   navigation={this.props.navigation}/>     </Stack.Navigator>
<NavigationContainer >
```

I can't understand why I can navigate from the AddScreen to the Save Screen, but I can't do the same between the profileScreen and the SaveProfileImage.

The save is this one:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, Image, Button } from 'react-native'

import firebase from 'firebase'
require('firebase/firestore')
require('firebase/firebase-storage')


export default function Save(props) {
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('')

    const uploadImage = async () => {
        const uri = props.route.params.image;
        const childPath =
            `post/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;

        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const task = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(childPath)
            .put(blob);

        const taskProgress = snapshot => {
            console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
        };

        const taskCompleted = () => {
            task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
                savePostData(snapshot);
            })
        };

        const taskError = snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot)
        };

        task.on('state_changed', taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);
    };

    const savePostData = (downloadURL) => {

        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('posts')
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .add({
                downloadURL,
                caption,
                likesCount: 0,
                estate: '',
                city: '',
                creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            }).then((function () {
                props.navigation.popToTop()
            }))
    };
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Image source={{ uri: props.route.params.image }} />
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Write a Caption . . .'
                onChangeText={(caption) => setCaption(caption)}
            />

            <Button title='Save' onPress={() => uploadImage()} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

The SaveProfileScreen is this other one:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, Image, Button } from 'react-native'

import firebase from 'firebase'
require('firebase/firestore')
require('firebase/firebase-storage')


export default function ProfileImage(props) {
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('')

    const uploadImage = async () => {
        const uri = props.route.params.image;
      const childPath =
          `profileImage/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/
            ${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
            console.log(childPath);

      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();

      const task = firebase
          .storage()
          .ref()
          .child(childPath)
          .put(blob);

      const taskProgress = snapshot => {
          console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
      };

      const taskError = snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot)
      };

      const taskCompleted = () => {
          task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
              savePictureData(snapshot);
          })
      };

      task.on('state_changed', taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Image source={{ uri: props.route.params.profileImage }} />

            <Button title='Save' onPress={() => uploadImage()} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: you need to make sure your ProfileImage functional component is one of the screens in the navigation container.

Comment: Yes, and it is. I have a Main.js where are all the screens I use after the user is logged in (The Add.js is inside this stack as also the Profile.js, which is the one I need to navigate to the SaveProfilePicture, but it is not working ), and the Add.js which navigates to the Save.js works, but the SaveProfilePicture.js, is not working for the navigation. I don't know what else I need to do to make this navigation work.
If I try to navigate from Profile.js to Save.js also I can't do this.

Comment: try to access the route props outside of a the async function.

Comment: I have used the add screen to pass the props to go to the SaveProfileImage.js instead of the Save.js screen, and it worked. So it has to be something inside my Profile.js screen, I need to find what it can be...